# write-behind cache store events are not invoked

Tags: oracle-coherence

I am trying to create a write behind cache in my Web Logic App server (There is a coherence cluster targeting this app server).
I have given server specific cache config in Server Start 'Arguments' (-Dtangosol.coherence.cacheconfig=/server/appserver/server-cache-config.xml).

**server-cache-config.xml:**

```
<cache-config>
  <caching-scheme-mapping>
    <cache-mapping>
      <cache-name>MissedTransactionCache</cache-name>
      <scheme-name>Missed-Transaction-Cache</scheme-name>
    </cache-mapping>
  </caching-scheme-mapping>

  <caching-schemes>
    <distributed-scheme>
      <scheme-name>missed-transaction-cache-scheme</scheme-name>
      <service-name>DistributedCache</service-name>

      <thread-count>50</thread-count>

      <backing-map-scheme>
        <read-write-backing-map-scheme>
          <scheme-name>TestScheme</scheme-name>

          <internal-cache-scheme>
            <local-scheme>
              <scheme-ref>categories-eviction</scheme-ref>
            </local-scheme>
          </internal-cache-scheme>

          <cachestore-scheme>
            <class-scheme>
              <class-name>com.example.MissedTransactionCacheStore</class-name>
            </class-scheme>
          </cachestore-scheme>

          <write-delay>30s</write-delay>
          <write-batch-factor>0.9</write-batch-factor>
        </read-write-backing-map-scheme>
      </backing-map-scheme>

      <listener>
        <class-scheme>
          <class-name>com.example.MissedTransactionCacheListener</class-name>
        </class-scheme>
      </listener>
    </distributed-scheme>

    <local-scheme>
      <scheme-name>categories-noneviction</scheme-name>
    </local-scheme>
  </caching-schemes>
</cache-config>
```

I do not see any exceptions during server start and cache interaction (get,put,etc) even the listener (MissedTransactionCacheListener) events are getting triggered, but there are no store operations happening. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<cache-mapping>
  <cache-name>MissedTransactionCache</cache-name>
  <scheme-name>Missed-Transaction-Cache</scheme-name>

<distributed-scheme>
  <scheme-name>missed-transaction-cache-scheme</scheme-name>
```

The scheme names don't match.